# Unable to locate factory in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am making a unit test for PHPunit. The code is:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ThreadTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;



    public function test_a_thread_has_replies()
    {

        $thread = factory('App\Thread')->create();

        $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection', $thread->replies);
    }
}
```

When I run PHPUnit i get the error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory for [App\Thread].

I have a threadfactory:

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Thread;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Thread::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory(App\User::class),
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'body' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

If I use the factory in Tinker it works fine.

I have similar testfunctions and factories for other classes and these work fine.

Most likely I am making a very stupid error, but I cannot find it.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,

HUbert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are extending the php unit testcase class. Which does not load your Laravel application. You should extends the use `Tests\TestCase` provided by Laravel.

Using php artisan `make:test UserTest` on the CLI will create a test with the correct template fitting for testing a Laravel application.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Did it, but nothing changes. The ExampleTest.php that is included in the Laravel distribution is also exactly like my test. So the problem must be another one.

Comment: I fiddled around and in the end the problem was solved by the way you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use

```html
$factory->define(App\Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
//return code here
}
```

Instead of just using the Model name without placing APP\ in front of the model name

```html
$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
//return code here
}
```